# How to show consolidated Firebase data?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform

Here the challenge is I have been managing 5 different mobile apps and each has a separate Firebase Project.

So to view crash logs, and total downloads and to get other firebase details I need to visit each project separately.

I am looking for a solution that provides me with all the app data on one page.

i.e. Web page that shows all apps details. That saves my time to visit each app.

How would I achieve this? Is Firebase provide any API through which I can fetch details?

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a solution that provides me with all app data on one page.

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to view the data within 5 projects in a single place.

> Firebase provides any API through which I can fetch details?

No, it doesn't. You have to view the data in each project separately.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the question, but is this applicable? [Configure Multiple Projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects) or [Working with multiple Firebase projects in an Android app](https://firebase.blog/posts/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app)

Comment: @Jay As I understand. the OP wants to view in one place all details (analytics) of 5 separate projects.

Comment: Ah yes. App *details*, not app *data*. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Hey Rohan. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?